# Rails Asset Pipeline Precompile CSS Not Functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets, actionview

Hey I have am running into a problem with a css.scss file not showing up after precompiling in production.  The error is a ActionView::Template::Error when a page is rendered

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 343ms

ActionView::Template::Error (signup.css isn't precompiled):
```

The signup.css is referenced inside of new.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag("signup.css") %>
```

I have ran rake assets:precompile and bundle exec rake assets:precompile just to make sure it wasn't an environment problem.

In my production.rb i have the following line so make sure that it is included

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(dashboard.css dashboard.js signup.css)
```

**UPDATE:**
This may not be related because I was precompiling locally and then FTPing my files up to the servers public/assets directory, but whenever I try to precompile on my server I am getting a block in the shell runner when compliing javascript

```
gemfile 
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

Also I have nodejs installed on the server from the chris lee repository.

**UPDATE 2:**

So I restarted my server and it looks like all of the files are going to precompile on the server using 
    rake assets:precompile

However it does give me an error right at the end

```
luna@domU-12-31-39-14-04-80:~/apps/legalleads$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/luna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby /home/luna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace


** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (): [/home/luna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin...]
/home/luna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...i've been struggling with this for weeks and it seems like i'm following the guides for having a javascript environment setup.

Comment: run rake assets:precompile again and try restarting the server

Comment: can you try and run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by giving up on server side compilation and just using git to manage and publish my assets that I precompile locally.